# THREE Light 360 degree

Tags: three.js

How to make light which is lighting like SUN in the Space, that's mean from one center point in the middle of scene evenly in all directions.

Spotlight has limited angle
Directional light is not possible to use in both directions from the star sides.

Only idea I had is to positing a huge number of spotlights in one position rotated to all directions, butthis is not optimal solution, not CPU, GPU cost safe..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A [THREE.PointLight](http://threejs.org/docs/#Reference/Lights/PointLight) casts light in all directions.